# Initialising more than two mpz_t using mpz_set_str causes segfault

Tags: c, gmp

Anyone know why the following results in a seg fault after the second call to mpz_set_str()? How can I initialise more than two gmp ints from str?

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        mpz_t a, b, c;

        mpz_set_str(a, "10", 10);
        printf("gets here a\n");
        mpz_set_str(b, "20", 10);
        printf("gets here b\n");
        mpz_set_str(c, "30", 10);
        printf("gets here c\n");
}
```

compiled with: `gcc -lm -lgmp -o segf segf.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `mpz_set_str`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#index-mpz_005fset_005fstr) says:

> **5.2 Assignment Functions**
>
> These functions assign new values to already initialized integers (see [Initializing Integers](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html#Initializing-Integers)).
>
> ...

The link goes to

> **5.1 Initialization Functions**
>
> The functions for integer arithmetic assume that all integer objects are initialized. You do that by calling the function `mpz_init`. For example,
>
> ```
> {
>   mpz_t integ;
>   mpz_init (integ);
>   …
>   mpz_add (integ, …);
>   …
>   mpz_sub (integ, …);
>
>   /* Unless the program is about to exit, do ... */
>   mpz_clear (integ);
> }
> ```
>
> As you can see, you can store new values any number of times, once an object is initialized.

Your code doesn't initialize the variables, so assignment functions such as `mpz_set_str` produce garbage.